# How to properly design game state machine with internal conditional transitions

Tags: java, state, state-machine

I am having the following states which are designed to simulate game states

```
enum GameStates{ Bet, CompleteBet, Bonus,CompleteBonus, Jackpot, CompleteJackpot }
```

Only `Bet` state is external for the game (can be triggered from outside). Every other state is internal, that is triggered by the game itself.

If I am in `CompleteBet` state, the game can proceed to `Bonus` state, but also can be returned back to `Bet` state (this is per game configuration).

The same situation is repeated when in `CompleteBonus` state. The game can transit itself to `Bet` or `Jackpot` state.

Right now I am handling this situation with the following `if - else` logic

```
    // In CompleteBet state
    if (bonus.isEnabled) {
        setState(Bonus);
    } else {
        if (jackpot.isEnabled) {
            setState(Jackpot);
        } else {
            setState(Bet);
        }

        // in CompleteBonus state
        if (jackpot.isEnabled) {
            setState(Jackpot);
        } else {
            setState(Bet);
        }
    }
```

But obviously that's not good solution. Maybe I need to redesign my state machine? Any suggestions are appreciated

Edit:
 Actually `GameState` enum is defined like so:

```
enum GameState implements TransferState {
    WITHDRAW {
        @Override
        public void initiateStep(final GameContext context) {
            //some logic which triggers complete transfer
        }
    },

    COMPLETE_WITHDRAW {
        @Override
        public void completeTransfer(final GameContext context) {
            // if bonus is enabled;
            if (true) {
                context.setState(BONUS);
            } else {
                // if remote gaming is on
                if (true) {
                    context.setState(REMOTE_GAME);
                } else {
                    context.setState(WITHDRAW);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

`initiateTransfer` and `completeTransfer` are defined as `default` methods in `TransferState` interface.

Comment: I would have use a State Patter , look this references https://www.baeldung.com/java-state-design-pattern

Comment: I am using it. I have a game context witch delegates its actions to my state. Excerpts of the code are from handling methods of my states

Comment: No you don't use the Patter state, because the state is an object and not an enum

Comment: Oh now is ok, The chain of responsability pattern resolve your problem

Comment: I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would have use the **State Patter** with a **chain of responsibility pattern**, and example for your case

The your game

```
public class Game{


    private IState state = new StateReady();

    public void play(){
        state.play(this);
    }

    public void setState(IState state){
        this.state = state;
    }


}
```

A state

```
public StateReady implements IState{

        private List<IGameHeadler> headler = new ArrayList<>();

        public StateReady(){
            headler.add(new BonusHeadler());
            headler.add(new JackpotHeadler());
        }

        public void play(Game game){
            //Your operation
            //an example the operation is
            Iterator iterator = headler.iterator();
            boolean flag = false;
            while(iterator.hasNext() && !flag){
                IGameHeadler headler = (IGameHeadler)iterator.next();
                flag = headler.doChain();

            }
            game.setState(new WaitState(game));
        }
}
```

Common interfaces

```
public interface IGameHeadler{

    boolean doChain();
}

public interface IState{

    void play(Game game);
}
```

But the state of the game would change to

1. An external thread
2. The Game class
3. The another state
4. Any object, the pattern is an idea that offers a solution to a known problem but this idea can be extended depending on the case

Also, the chain of responsibility pattern is a cool mode for divide the your logic in more headler, in your case one headler is `If()`

Also, I preferer used another patter for create a state, one state is unique and the **flyweight pattern** resolve this problem I would have removed the enum